# Yii задать имя отправителя письма

Tags: email, php, yii

Использую расширение для Yii [YiiMailMessage](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/mail/)

Вот столкнулся с проблемой, **как задать имя отправителя** вместо адреса эл.почты?

Отправляю следующим образом:

```
$mail = new YiiMailMessage;
$mail->view = 'viewfile';
$mail->subject = 'subject mail';
$mail->setBody(array('data1'=>$data1, "data2"=>$data2), 'text/html');
$mail->addTo($user->email);
$mail->from = Yii::app()->params['emails']['admin'];
Yii::app()->mail->send($mail);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я всё правильно понял, то вот так

```
$mail->setTo(array( $user->email => 'Имя Юзера' ));
```

Извиняюсь, перепутал.
Отправителя вот так:

```
$mail->setFrom(array( 'email' => 'name' ));
```